# making one property strong,nonatomic for objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a multi view application and use an object to keep track of my logged in user. My User.h looks like this

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *data;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *uid;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *dob;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *gender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *avatarURL;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger status;

- (void)setPropertiesWith:(NSDictionary *)data;
```

And the User.m looks like this

```
#import "User.h"

@implementation User
/*
 * set properties
 */
- (void)setPropertiesWith:(NSDictionary *)data{
    self.data = data;

    self.uid = self.data[@"uid"];
    self.firstName = self.data[@"firstName"];
    self.lastName = self.data[@"lastName"];
    self.dob = self.data[@"dob"];
    self.gender = self.data[@"gender"];
    self.status = [[self.data valueForKeyPath:@"status"] intValue];
    self.avatarURL = self.data[@"avatarURL"];
}

@end
```

I had the data as weak, but in one of the views it would turn up null - I believe ARC was releasing it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I have 2 questions:

1. With this setup, the data being `strong` and the rest of the properties being `weak`, is there any potential risk to this?
2. Should I make the data an ivar and keep the rest as is?

There is no actual reason(other than my poor class design skills) for the existence of the properties. I just find it very interesting and wanted to understand what is going on.

Comment: Why did you make the properties weak?

Comment: @rmaddy novice mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> 1. With this setup, the data being `strong` and the rest of the properties being `weak`, is there any potential risk to this?

Yes, if you `nil` the `dictionary`, all of your properties would likely become `nil`, assuming you don’t have other strong references to them elsewhere.

> 2. Should I make the data an ivar and keep the rest as is?

I wouldn’t even make it an ivar (unless there’s some other requirement for saving this that you haven’t shared with us). It should just be a local variable, and make your properties `copy` (or `strong`).

---

I’d suggest (a) getting rid of the `NSDictionary` property and (b) making the `NSString` properties be `copy` (or `strong`), not `weak`. Also, rather than having a `setPropertiesWith` method, I’d just define an initializer:

```
// User.h

@interface User : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *uid;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *dob;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *gender;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *avatarURL;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger status;

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

@end
```

And

```
// User.m

@implementation User

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.uid       = dictionary[@"uid"];
        self.firstName = dictionary[@"firstName"];
        self.lastName  = dictionary[@"lastName"];
        self.dob       = dictionary[@"dob"];
        self.gender    = dictionary[@"gender"];
        self.status    = [dictionary[@"status"] intValue];
        self.avatarURL = dictionary[@"avatarURL"];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

And then, the caller would do:

```
User *user = [[User alloc] initWithDictionary:someDictionary];
```

There are other refinements you could consider here (e.g. `readonly` public interface, declaring nullability, lightweight generics on the dictionary, etc.), but the above is probably a good starting point.

---

By the way, if your wondering why I made these `copy` instead of `strong`, we just want to protect ourselves in case the caller passed a `NSMutableString` (which is a `NSString` subclass) and accidentally mutated it later. This is just a bit safer, a little more defensive pattern.